# The shell theorem and net torque

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, rotational-dynamics, torque

Consider the setup shown in the picture. A spherical uniform density mass of $m_1$ is connected to a ball-and-joint socket via a bar of negligible mass. Another spherical uniform density mass $m_2$ applies a gravitational force on $m_1,$ producing a torque. Now, the shell theorem tells us that the net *force* of $m_2$ on $m_1$ is equivalent to the scenario where both masses were point masses.

But does the shell theorem imply that we can treat all of the mass as being concentrated at the center when calculating the net *torque*? I think not, and I don't see any reason *a priori* why this should be the case, but perhaps there is a nice way to show that it actually is the case[image].

Answer (score 0):

The shell theorem only tells you what the gravitational field of mass $m_1$ looks like for $m_2$, namely like that of a point mass of equal mass. How any external constraint effects the resultant motion of $m_1$ is irrelevant for this. It would be the same for a point mass, simply because this is what $m_2$ 'sees' at any instant.